# How to Remove Acrotray.EXE

Tags: boot

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5215329_remove-acrotrayexe.html) , but process still runs on mu PC? How to stop it to autostart?

Comment: Did you reboot as instructed in that link ?

Comment: think he rebooted at least 1000 times on today.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1051735/disable-adobe-acrotray-exe-from-starting-at-boot

Answer (score 1):

I would check msconfig again, it may have been re-enabled.

Comment: its disabled in msconfig

Answer (score 1):

This should be showing the same information as MsConfig but it might be worth trying this alternative tool instead:

[AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Best tools to clean up your autostarts, registry and files etc is [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download).